# solr facet query sum on distinct values

Tags: solr

I have data as following in solr

```
id,subid,value
1,101,1000
1,101,1000
1,102,1050
1,103,1060
2,110,100
2,110,100
2,113,130
```

now i want query solr such as

```
SELECT id, sum(value) 
FROM (SELECT distinct id, subid, value 
      from table)
GROUP BY id
```

My expected ouput is

```
1,3110
2,230
```

I tried to do group query but it only allows one column to group in solr.

I tried to run a facet query but it considers duplicate records for subid 101 and 110.

Comment: Do you need distinct across the `value` column as well, or only over the `id` and `subid` columns?

Comment: Yes, I need to count value at once for distinct id and subid